# Access 2007 - Catch-22 using a global function in a query

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have Form A that passes a PK to Form B (using OpenForm). The OnLoad event of Form B uses that PK to populate a few text boxes. There is also a ListBox on Form B that I want to populate with an Access query accessing a different table using that PK value.

I learned from this forum that I have to create a new global function to pass in a variable in the Where/Criteria of the query.  I have done this and hard-coded the value in the function just to make sure I had that concept correct and I was able to get it to work.  Now the catch-22 comes when I replace the hard-coded value in the function and try to pass in a variable (the original PK).  But that function is only called via the where clause in the query.  If I could get the value of the PK to the query I wouldn't need the function.  Is there a way to use the query at this point or do I have to put all the DB access in the VBA?  Do I make sense on this?  Hopefully, what I have done is not a throw-away.

One thing I thought of was to make a global variable, set its value to the PK in the Load Form and it should be accessible to the function.  Ideas on that or a better way?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as it seems, you want to get the PK from the first form into a query that populates something on the second form, then you could refer to the control on the first form in the query that populates the second. The following can be entered as a query-criteria:

```
Forms!FormA!txtBoxPrimary
```

Using VBA (and Where clauses) offers more control, and error-handling possibilities, but it *is* possible to refer to a form-control directly in an Access Query.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try that. I'm new to Access - never thought of that and didn't realize that was an option.  I'm learning a lot. Thanks!